# Paypal recurring payment with variable amount every month

Tags: node.js, paypal

My problem is, the amount will differ every cycle but in recurring I have to pass only one fix amount which is depend on customers how they use our service.

I read reference transaction doc but i didn't got whole point.

I don't have any problem with manage from my side and set charge to user dynamically by my side but how it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal is not providing metered billing concept. For that I have use STRIPE later that time.